# Was Yirmiyahu HaNabi a descendant of Pinchas HaKohen?

Tags: kohen-priest, genealogy, pinchas, pinchas-the-man, jeremiah

While reading this week's Torah and Haftarah portions Pinchas ([פִּינְחָס‎](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading_cdo/aid/2495776/p/1/jewish/Pinchas-Torah-Reading.htm)) & Yirmiyahu ([Jeremiah](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?aid=2495776&p=haftarah&jewish=)),  I began to wonder if Yirimiyahu HaNabi was of the line of Pinchas HaKohen.  Outside of both being Levites and descendants of Aaron HaKohen, was Yirimiyahu HaNabi a direct descendant of Pinchas HaKohen?....I did come across this piece of information suggesting that Yirimiyahu HaNabi could possibly be of the line of Ithamar and not of El'azar HaKohen ([Here](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8586-jeremiah#anchor3)). As always personal insights, commentaries, articles, and resources are welcomed and very much so appreciated. Todah Rabbah.

Comment: This question was marked down without any explanation. Is there a particular reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radak Yirmiyahu 1:1 says that Yirmiyahu's father was Chilkiyahu ben Shalom - חלקיהו בן שלום. Chilkiyahu ben Shalom ben Tzadok came from the Bnei Tzadok [that are Meyuchas to Pinchas.](https://www.kolhalashon.com/PDF/Shiurim/01439/01439545.pdf) see page 8.